# How to structure Laravel applications when not using Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and am working on a collection of API endpoints that fetch data from a variety of database tables, transforms and processes that data, and then returns it as a JSON response. What I'm struggling to decide, from reading the documentation, is where my processing/transformation code should live.

I've setup my routes in routes/api.php, and have them point towards a `Controller` subclass, but from here things get a little murky because I'm not currently looking to make use of Eloquent ORM. It seems like typically I'd generate `Model` subclasses for each database table, and have a `Repository` call into those and transform the returned data, like so:

```
Route => Controller => Repository => Model
```

But where should I be placing both the database query code, and the logic required to process/transform that data (the business logic), when not making use of Eloquent ORM or the `Model` paradigm? Making the controller fat with DB queries and logic seems like a messy solution, but at the same time a lot of the Laravel DB example code *does* place logic in Controller subclasses.

Comment: So you don't want to write models and yet at the same time you don't want for your controllers to take too much of responsibility? Those are the opposites, you can't sit on two stools at the same time. If a lot of your queries and logic is shared among different controllers then you need to write models to keep your code nice and dry. If it's something simple, then you don't need to overcomplicate things and you can keep everything in your controllers.

Comment: @d3jn No, that's not what I'm saying at all. Rather, the Laravel [Model](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html) class *seems* to have a host of Eloquent ORM-specific functionality that I don't want automatically invoked. I'm asking if there's an alternative to the Model class that can be used for direct DB calls.

Comment: Noone forces you to use `Eloquent` class. You can write your own `Model` class that will be only data containers and `Repository` that will be mapping it into your models or saving it using Laravel's `Query Builder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can setup your project without `Eloquent`.

1. Models are just data containers (records). They don't know how or where to store themselves. They are instantiated with some data and provide access for it:

```php
class OrderRecord
{
    protected $id;
    protected $createdAt;

    public function __construct($id, $createdAt = null)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt ?: date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    }

    public function getID()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    ...
}
```

2. You read and write models only via repositories. Repository is just a class with your typical methods to retrieve/write one or multiple records (find, findAll, update, delete etc). It reads data, instantiates record(s) with it or take record(s), gets data from them and writes it. For example:

```php
class OrderRepository
{
    public function find($id): OrderRecord
    {
        // Here goes your querying. StdClass will be returned in this case
        // that will be used to create new record.
        $row = DB::table('orders')->find($id);

        if ($row) {
            return (new OrderRecord($row->id, $row->created_at));
        } else {
            // If not found you can throw an exception or return null 
            // (return type should be ?OrderRecord then) depending on 
            // how you want to design your workflow with repositories.
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

3. Lastly your business logic can be in your controllers. Your controllers should use repositories to get your model objects, work with them and the use repositories to store result if needed.
4. Obviously, you will need to implement base classes/interfaces for all your entities. Use dependency injection and Laravel's service container to glue everything together.

You can also extend this design by separating querying and mapping in your repository - you will have `Repository` classes that know only how to retrieve/store raw data and you will have `Mapper` classes that know how to create/retrieve raw data to/from your records (and serve as factories that repository will use to generate record objects from query results). If business logic also need to be interchangeable then you can also take business logic out of your controllers and put it into separate classes that your controller can utilize.

[Here](https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/) is an excellent article about repository-based approach and how you can extend it.

Answer (score 1):

So I'll offer an approach that is I think accomplishes what you are asking. In the API I developed, I used the `route/api.php` file to create the API endpoints. Each of these point to a `Controller` where the authentication and request validation is performed. The `Controller` then calls a `Service` class that handles all the business logic of the application and these are the real heavy lifting parts. The `Service` class makes calls to a `Repository`, which actually performs `Model` changes and saving.

I saw this used in another project several years ago and mimicked it for my projects. The code flow is shown below. Not sure if it will work for you, but I find it to be a very neat and keeps the code grouped together in logical ways.

```
Route => Controller => Service => Repository => Model
```

Comment: Thank you! I suppose one source of my confusion is that in all of the examples of Model usage I've seen, it appears that the underlying class handles setting up the database connection and fetching data. But I can't find any information on when or how this is performed (is it done lazily after the first fetch request, etc). So is it safe to use a Model subclass and perform my own database connection from within it?